# Easy way to convert web forms to MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I haven't worked with MVC3 that much - as it was just released, but I was wondering if there was some kind of conversion tool - to convert exisiting Views / Forms into the newer up-to-date "Razor" view engine.

I'm not sure if it is possible but I just thought this would be the place to ask...

Thanks!

Comment: fwiw, I've converted some views manually and found it to be easy and smooth.  Granted, our views were fairly simple.

Comment: Yeah this is an "initiative" that someone where I work thought would be for the best...to waste time to convert all existing stuff to MVC3, including recently created MVC2 apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently read on [Dave Hayden's blog](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/) this morning about Telerik releasing a Razor View Conversion tool. I believe they used it to convert all of their demos on their site from all of their existing WebForm view to the new Razor View engine.

[Here](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/20/WebFormRazorViewConversionToolTelerik.aspx) is Dave's short blurb regarding the tool and if you want to play around with it yourself, it is available on Github using the following link:

[Github - Telerik Razor Conversion Tool](https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter)

Hope this helps you out (I haven't had the chance to play around with it much - but knowing Telerik, it's probably pretty decent.)

Answer (score 1):

Given that Asp.net webforms works well for simple pages and there is no point in moving to MVC for **the sake of it**.   I don't think a converter will do a good job, as:

- your pages are complex
- and/or you wish to do unit testing - so need to redesign
- or you are moving for the sake of it (way?)

Comment: No point in moving to MVC if you are using WebForms? Actually there are a number of reasons you should move away from WebForms, however I am not going to go into detail. Ill leave you with one example: Page Size. Take one of your WebForm pages and convert it to an MVC View and you will see a HUGE difference in size. Smaller page size means your pages load faster, which is great for the end user.